# Geolocation through React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, geolocation, react-redux

I am trying to get a better understanding of redux and react lifecycle method.

I have a prop function on component did mount that calls a function in redux. On redux I am calling the location to get the position and setting the initial state and updating it when the call gets made. I am able to get the position but no matter what I've tried through redux, my coords(initial state) still comes out as undefined. I tried a .then() on the componentDidMount function and set state locally and this worked. But I would like to use this feature with redux to try and get a better understanding of it. My understanding is that as long as there is an initial state, there should not be a problem in updating it. But I feel that my problem may be somewhere with my action.payload. As it is not logging anything in my switch case for GET_LOCATION. One thing of note, i get a yellow warning on my console, '[Violation] Only request geolocation information in response to a user gesture.' I am not sure if this impacts anything. Anyways, any suggestions would be vastly appreciated. I've searched high and low for a nice solution to geolocation through redux. Here is the code:

```
const initialState = {
    coords: { }
};


export function getLocation() {
    const geolocation = navigator.geolocation;
          return {
             type: GET_LOCATION,
             payload: geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                 console.log(position.coords)
                 return position
             })
         }

};
```

Switch Statement:

```
case GET_LOCATION:
    console.log(GET_LOCATION)
        return Object.assign({},
            state,
            {
                coords: action.payload
            }
        )
```

Comment: Need more code to understand. you can add a minimal running snippet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, so it's not returning anything to put in payload.

You need to use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) to dispatch asynchronously. Follow the instructions to set it up if you've never used it, then you should be able to change your action creator like this:

```
export function getLocation() {
    return dispatch => {
        const geolocation = navigator.geolocation;
        geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            console.log(position.coords);
            dispatch({
                type: GET_LOCATION,
                payload: position
            });
        });
};
```

Comment: How would you do the error handling for this? I understand you have turned position into the dispatch function, as it requires a function for a successful callback.

Comment: getCurrentPosition() takes a second argument which is the error callback. In there you could do another dispatch with a different type like GET_LOCATION_FAILED. Then in the reducer switch statement, you'd have another case for GET_LOCATION_FAILED and do whatever you need to do in there.

Comment: Thank you a ton. I managed to figure out how to implement it

`export const getGeolocation = () => async dispatch => {
  const geolocation = navigator.geolocation;
  geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    position => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_GEOLOCATION,
        payload: position.coords
      });
    },
    error => {
      if (error.code === 1) {
        dispatch({
          type: GEOLOCATION_DENIED,
          payload: false
        });
      }
    }
  );
};`

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue, even though I could console.log the coordinates within the promise success case, I wasn't able to get the state to update. You need to nest the promise inside a function in the action creator. This allows you to call the dispatch function within the resolve case, dispatching the data to the reducers with the data asynchronously. See below:

```
export const location = () => {
    return function (dispatch) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (!navigator.geolocation) {
                reject(new Error('Not Supported'));
            }
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                var action = {
                    type: FETCH_LOCATION,
                    payload: {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        long: position.coords.longitude,
                        time: position.timestamp
                    }
                }
                resolve(position);
                dispatch(action)
            }, () => {
                reject(new Error('Permission denied'));
            });
        });
    }
};
```